# Selenium error: UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-rc

I am getting the following error when i execute the following command:

```
text = idobi Radio: New. Music. Unfiltered. idobi.com - a SHOUTcast.com member station    
self.se.is_element_present("css=a[href]:contains('idobi Radio: New. Music. Unfiltered. idobi.com - a SHOUTcast.com member station')")
```

The title I am searching for on the website, is as follows:

```
idobi Radio: New. Music. Unfiltered. idobi.com - a SHOUTcast.com member station
```

The whole error i get is :

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)
```

could someone please help me with this issue?

thanks.

Comment: Please paste all code that could be relevant, and the whole traceback, not just that line.

Comment: I am running selenium using python and only this error is showing up on the following line: self.se.is_element_present

Comment: Let me rephrase: Paste the _whole_ python source, and the _whole_ output of the execution of the script. The current code and output is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium itself is Unicode-safe.  It's probably a pure-Python problem, not a Selenium problem.

Comment: I did figure out the problem. Actually I had '...' in the text which I was trying to compare. This '...' somehow is always taken as u'\u2026' in the string by Python. Hence, while the comparison, there was an error